# How to send custom email in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, email

I am very new to MAGENTO, I have build a brand new extension. So i have created form now i want to send all details in html to admin as well as guest user.I am using below code for it.

```
$mail = new Zend_Mail();
$mail->setBodyText($mydata);
$mail->setFrom($guestEmail);
$mail->addTo('test@gmail.com', 'Some Recipient');
$mail->setSubject('Test su');
$mail = Mage::getModel('core/email');
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Can you be more clear. Are you getting an error? Is it not sending? Is email in general working?

Comment: i am getting row html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few days ago i have created a extension for it i am posting code here, hope it will help you.

```
<?php
class Arunendra_Headerchanger_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action{
   public function sendemailAction()
    {
        //Fetch submited params
        $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
        $firstName = $this->getRequest()->getParams('First-Name');
        $lastName = $this->getRequest()->getParams('Last-Name');
        $email = $this->getRequest()->getParams('Email');
        $fullName = $firstName.' '. $lastName;

        $result = array_filter($params, 'strlen' );
        $str = '<table><tr><th>Field:</th><th>Value:</th></tr>';
        foreach($result as $key => $value){
        $str .='<tr>';
        $str .=  '<td>'.$key.':</td><td>'.$value.'</td>';
        $str .= '</tr>';

        }
        $str .=  '</table>';    
        $mail = Mage::getModel('core/email');
        $mail->setToName('Arunendra');
        $mail->setToEmail('arunendra.gct@gmail.com');
        $mail->setBody($str);
        $mail->setSubject('Pre-Employment Application');
        $mail->setFromEmail($email);
        $mail->setFromName($fullName);
        $mail->setType('html');// You can use 'html' or 'text'
        try {
            $mail->send();
            Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('Your request has been sent');
        }        
        catch(Exception $ex) {
            Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('Unable to send email.');

        }

        //Redirect back to index action of (this) inchoo-simplecontact controller
             $this->_redirect('careerform');
    }

}
```